# Best optimization method for minimizing error of estimated default probability

Tags: optimization, regression-analysis, logistic-regression, robust-statistics

The credit risk modelling problem can be stated as:
$$
\min_{a \in \mathbb{R}^{1 \times n}} \sum_i \Big( d_i -\frac{\exp(a x_i) }{1+\exp(a x_i)}\Big)^2
$$
Where $ d_i \in \mathbb{N} \in [0,1] $ is the default indicator for customer $ i $ and  $ x_i \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1} $ is the value of all the $ n $ information variables available for customer $ i $.
Any alternatives to logistic regression?

Comment: This might fare better at stats (dot) stackexchange (dot) com, since the question seems to be about choice among various models rather than about the actual mathematics (although understanding of the math is relied upon heavily). $\qquad$

Comment: I haven't seen this done by least squares before. With the simplest linear regression models, least squares coincides with maximum likelihood. With logistic regression, it does not, and maximum likelihood rather than least squares is typically used.

Comment: The optimization problem you pose is very hard since it's not convex. Logistic regression solves a different optimization problem.